# Finding trunk commits not ending on master - Trunk based development with Azure repos

Tags: git, azure-repos, tbd

I have an implementation of Trunk Based Development in Azure Repos as follows:

1. Development on short live feature branch - multiple commits
2. PR to trunk - merge squash, delete feature branch
3. Cherry pick from trunk to release - Azure Repos does a new PR, hence a new commit id
4. Merge release branch to master - basic merge preserving history
5. Delete release branch after fixes.

Are there tools in Azure Repos or git that would actually allow to check which commits from trunk didn't end up in master?

Comment: You may want to mention in your question details about you will need to identify commits, since you can't use commit ids (based on your comment on my earlier answer) and include some sample output.

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm using Azure Repos for everything, haven't I mentioned that?

Comment: I'm not sure that really tells anybody anything. If you don't provide an accurate description of the problem you're trying to solve, you're not going to get good answers.

Comment: You mean good pure git answers. Azure repos has a lot of it's features hidden (implemented on the server side available via APIs or available via UI only). Doing a Cherry-Pick in azure doesn't actually mean to do a cherry pick in git. Not to mention doing a cherry pick of a PR commit. But maybe for someone that knows azure better than I there's an obvious solution. If I won't get any good answers, I'll repost or better edit this as pure git question, where I would provide all commits description etc.